# Question misconception on stackexchange

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange

Unfortunately , staff on blender.stackexchange act like they're robots and won't read the peoples question and close them immediately.

I don't know what is this unlikely and unfriendly action means, I had a question for days posting days after days no one answers and always misguidance to getting lost.

Here is an example of me asking a question about : **How to properly use specular pbr textures in blender?** and waiting for answer for a long time and all of a sudden after my very own answer score hunters in stack exchange came up and dislike my very own answer and posted their nonsense meaningless and misguiding answer and comments and when they realize they don't have an answer or maybe any knowledge at all.

They tried to spam their way by reporting my question as duplicate to this question ***"How to plug specular map into Principled Shader?"*** and as the title says that clearly it has something to do with principled shader and it isn't related , the user is trying to close this topic and hides it from public *im sure is "Duarte Farrajota Ramos ".

I believe that he is abusing his own power (may I mistaken) to hide something like this from community* , for example people shouldn't know how to use physically accurate PBR textures in blender hence he get less competitor
[How to properly use specular pbr textures in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265472/how-to-properly-use-specular-pbr-textures-in-blender)

Comment: Hello and welcome. If you feel any of you questions was incorrectly marked as duplicate or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, see [Help page about duplicates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) particularly the last paragraph. You can also flag your post for moderator attention with a short comment describing the issue so it can be reopened. Questions are frequently marked as duplicates (some times unfortunately incorrectly), it is a normal procedure for this site, don't t take it personally, they can always be reopened.

Comment: As for getting no answers see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers). Regarding the downvotes voting is a central part of this community, and every user gets to do it at his own discretion. If you got a downvote don't take it personally, in the end good content will rise and bad one will sink. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos sorry Im a little bit confused , can you please tell me the relevance between "connecting specular map to principled shader" and using "specular workflow in blender " ? if they have common words it doesn't mean they're related , yes i do edited my post and mentioned that it does not related to that question and wasn't answered there either .

Comment: We don't get notified of edits, but we do have review queues for reopen flags, which will be dealt with in due time.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos sorry my friend , i never meant to take anything personal , I do not know how to compensate ,you spend all of your time reading my problems , best regards ❤❤❤

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos check out the update

Comment: Please do not deface your post with unrelated questions. if you have a different issue that requires moderator action please post it in a new question, rather than edit it into you established question